# Jobs Started from .profile getting killed

Tags: linux, sudo, bash, nohup, .profile

Jobs which are triggered from OS Users `.profile` are getting killed after `Putty` Session is closed/exitted.

From the OS User "user1" jobs are triggered in application using `sudo` login to application id "app1".

1. .profile of user1

   ```
   set -o vi
   mesg y
   export PS1='$LOGNAME-$PWD>'
   export APP_GRP=ALL
   ./app_menu
   exit
   ```
2. in app_menu script 
   app_menu is triggered from user1 which logs in to Application ID "app1"

   ```
   sudo -u app1 -i run_jobs.sh
   ```
3. run_jobs.sh

   ```
   nohup jobname>/dev/null &
   pid=$!
   echo $pid
   wait $pid
   ```
4. JobName submits a process in `background` and completes. This running jobs is the main application job. 
   Now there is no issue till the putty session of the user1 is active. Once this `session` is `closed/timed out` the running process is `killed` automatically.

When the jobname is submitted directly to the app1 user from normal shell terminal using `nohup sudo -u app1 -i jobname>/dev/null &` , there is no issue.

Everytime the process is started using .profile , it is killed upon exiting the putty.

Have tried all the background options .

Please suggest solutions.